# Switch no me funciona en Laravel 4.3 - (plantilla blade)

Tags: laravel, blade

Estoy tratando de recorrer una información y mostrarla en base al parametro

```
@foreach($data as $file)
         @switch({{$file->seccion_separate}})
          @case(null)
           <li><button style="background: #eaeae8; color: #737476" class="btn btn-sm mb-1 btn-files" value="{{$file->name}}"><span class="fa fa-share"></span> {{$file->name}}</button></li>
          @break
         @endswitch
@endforeach
```

pero no me funciona lo unico que aparece en la pantalla es

```
@switch(prepago) @case(null)
```

como si estuviera haciendo un `print`

**Alguien sabe que esta pasando?**

Answer (score 1):

Pues `@switch` ha sido ingresado en `blade` desde la versión de laravel 5.5 asi que **NO** podrías utilizarlo en su versión  4.3.

Claro que siempre están el: `@if`, y el: `@elseif` para poder programar.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el problema es que esta usando llaves en la variable del switch. No deberia llevar llaves

```
@foreach ($data as $file)
    @switch($file->seccion_separate)
        @case(null)
            <li><button style="background: #eaeae8; color: #737476" class="btn btn-sm mb-1 btn-files" value="{{$file->name}}"><span class="fa fa-share"></span> {{$file->name}}</button></li>
            @break
    @endswitch
@endforeach
```